# Creating a text file from php script every 5 minutes

Tags: php, windows-7, batch-file, wampserver

Am using Windows7 Task Scheduler to run a php script to create a file  every 5 minutes, but am having  a problem with the batch file,it doesn't give me any errors but it's not creating the file either

```
   start php.exe C:\wamp\www\temp.php
```

maybe i have a terrible mistake here that's why i need help! its my first time writing or using a batch file...
if i run the batch file directly (double clicking on it) it creates the file so the problem might be in the task scheduler?!

this is the PHP file

```
<?php

$filename=date("d-m-y",time());
$myFile = $filename.'.txt';
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = rand(0,100);

$stringData=$stringData."*";


fwrite($fh, $stringData);
//fwrite($fh, "\n");


fclose($fh);
?>
```

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: "if i run the batch file directly (double clicking on it) it creates the file so the problem might be in the task scheduler?" ... that probably means that PHP isn't being called correctly from the task scheduler.  Have you checked your system event logs? Maybe they'll say something.  Or you could just try to run it from the full path.  That said, overwriting the PATH environment variable is a very bad idea.

Comment: i noticed i deleted it from my code...obv yeat the php code isnt being called...what do you checking system event logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just run it like this?

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe C:\wamp\www\temp.php
```

Comment: where should I put this sentence?! i need to run t every 5 minutes

Comment: You would put that into the task scheduler.  Making sure to try it in command prompt first to make sure it'll run.  If it doesn't, the it will at least give you an error message.

Comment: well...it didnt do anything in the command prompt! so something is wrong with the path?!

Comment: There was no error message that was emitted?  Was the php file executed?

Comment: nop! for both! no error msgs but the file wasn't created either!
am gonna post the php file with my question i couldnt do it here

Comment: Have you checked your C:\ folder for the file?  Try providing an absolute path to the file you want to write to instead of a relative one.

Comment: OMG! thats it ! :(( i should've not re-checkedg the path from teh begging! it was obv.! Thanks aloooooot! =) i did learn alot searching for it lol

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the way you're setting the PATH variable it no longer knows where the `start` command resides. Consider ADDING that file path to your PATH variable instead of simply overwriting your PATH variable.